# Converting memory addresses

Tags: assembly

I have been searching around for this question but cant seem to find it. If I am in GDB disassembling code, how do I convert something like 0xfffffff4 to -0xc (i found the values online)

I am trying to implement how its done in Perl. I was using hex, but I have no idea what im doing:

```
print hex(shift);
```

Comment: It's called two's complement: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's two's complement http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

So, what you do is invert every bit, and then add 1.

For example 0xffffff04 would become 0x000000fb+1=0x000000fc

EDIT: and to change it back, you do the same thing: so 0x000000fc would become 0xffffff03+1=0xffffff04

Answer (score 1):

In a 32-bit register or memory access, `0xfffffff4` *is* `-0xc` (or `-12`)—assuming a modern CPU architecture, all of which use twos-complement.